# How to Setup Windows Network Adapters for TCP Communication via Ethernet Connection?

Tags: networking, ethernet

For troubleshooting a TCP Server problem, I connected two Windows PCs directly with an Ethernet cable. I want one PC to act as a server, the other as a client. I am using the Hercules utility.

I have configured the Ethernet adapters as follows:

[PC 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akOq6.png)

IP 192.168.100.100
Subnet 255.255.0.0

[PC 2:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZAbA.png)

IP 192.168.100.200
Subnet 255.255.0.0

PC 1 listens for a connection on port 4000. I can connect locally. But PC 2 fails to connect to 192.168.100.100 even though both should be in the same network. I have tried different ports too, which does not solve the problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should try to open the TCP Port on the firewall of the PC 1

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall on PC 1 prevented the connection.

The problem is solved by allowing inbound access on port 4000 (or any other port respectively). Also make sure network access to the server application is allowed.

I had to reconfigure the firewall for the TCP Server application (Hercules utility), so that it is allowed to be connected to from public networks.
The direct Ethernet connection was classified as a public network and on first launch of Hercules I had chosen the default option for Windows Firewall to block connections from public networks. Which is why my setup did not work.